# How to specify label length in R for axis parameter. My label names are truncated

Tags: r, plot, label, axis, truncated

In R, I've created a plot with a separate axis on the left to specify horizontal labels for the y-axis of the plot.  However, the labels are truncated.  That is, the complete name is not shown, only the last 9 characters of the name is shown.  I use the R `axis` command to create the axis and the `labels = names` parameter to specify the names.  `names` is a vector of character label names which vary in length.

```
plot(x = c(0,mx),y=c(1,n),yaxt = 'n', xlab = "Dollars - 100,000's", cex.axis = .65, typ = 'n', ylab = '', cex.lab = .8)
axis(side = 2, at = seq(1,n), labels = names, las = 2, cex.axis = .65)
```

Here's what the plot looks like:
[Plot with truncated names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHlZf.png)

Comment: @dc37 That worked...Just adjusted the the left value a bit more from 4 to 8...worked great!  Thanks...

Comment: You're welcome ! Glad that it works !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the margin of your plot by passing the `mar` argument to `par` function:

```r
mar.default <- c(5,4,4,2) + 0.1
par(mar = mar.default + c(0, 4, 0, 0)) 
plot(x = c(0,mx),y=c(1,n),yaxt = 'n', xlab = "Dollars - 100,000's", cex.axis = .65, typ = 'n', ylab = '', cex.lab = .8)
axis(side = 2, at = seq(1,n), labels = names, las = 2, cex.axis = .65)
```

Without a reproducible example of your dataset, I can't guarantee that it will work right away, maybe you will have to adjust it on your own.

Otherwise, you can provide a reproducible example of your data: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)